# Handling session in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-5

The admin has the rights to activate deactivate user account. example image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Ies.jpg only activated user should be login that scenario has been completed successfully(used Boolean datatype admin=true&user=false).activated user have longed in browser if admin has deactivated her account.user should not do anything automatically leave to login page how to do it?**devise gem used**

### routes.rb

```
root to: 'application#home', as: :root   
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions',
                    registrations: 'users/registrations'
                  }
```

## controller# application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :authenticate_user!
def home
end
end
```

## model# user.rb

```
def is_admin?
  role == 0
end

def is_user?
  role == 1
end
```

## view# home.html.erb

```
<%if  current_user.is_admin?%>
  <%=  render 'layouts/admin' %>
<%else%>
  <%=  render 'layouts/user' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can nullify the user session token on user deactivate, it will automatically sign out the user. Or can call `sign_out user`

Answer (score 0):

user will sign out if he try to access any page and found to be deactived, checking it by `@current_user.active?`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :sign_out_unless_user_active

  def sign_out_unless_user_active
    sign_out @current_user unless @current_user.active?
  end

end
```

The problem is how you check user is active or inactive! As per that, change condition of `@current_user.active?`